# Swift generic type check protocol conformance

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Let's suppose I have 2 swift protocols:

```
protocol A: AnyObject {}

protocol B: A {}
```

On a generic function, I would like to retrieve if the passed type `T` can conform to the protocol `A`:

```swift
    func method<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> Bool {
        return T.self is A.Protocol // A.Type fails always
    }
```

On the previous method in case I send a type `A` everything works fine, but if I try to send a type that conforms `B` it fails. The expected result will be a true as B already conforms to A.

Is there any way to achieve this logic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *...can conform to the protocol...* checking at runtime is pretty *unswifty*. Write `method<T : A>` then you get the check at compile time

Comment: `A.Type` should work here. Can you show a [mcve] of `A.Type` failing? Anyway, why not check it at compile time (see George's answer)?

Comment: Yup I have already checked Georges's answer (and added a comment) If you try to pass a class type that conforms A or B, everything works fine, but let's suppose you want to pass protocol B as type, George's answer won't work

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of achieving this:

```
protocol A: AnyObject {}
protocol B: A {}

func method<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> Bool {
    return false
}
func method<T: A>(_ type: T.Type) -> Bool {
    return true
}


class Temp1: A {}
class Temp2: B {}
class Temp3 {}

print(method(Temp1.self)) // true
print(method(Temp2.self)) // true
print(method(Temp3.self)) // false
```

Write two methods the same, apart from one has generics `<T>` and the other is `<T: A>`. In this example, `Temp1` and `Temp2` will use the `<T: A>` method whereas `Temp3` will use just the `<T>` method since it doesn't conform to `A`.

Comment: Clever usage of overloading, I like it!

Comment: Thanks for the super fast response @George, but in your example, in case I want to pass `method(B.self)` as parameter, the result will be a `false`. Seems there's no inference on the type when sending a protocol type.

Comment: @AlbertoGarcía It doesn't really make sense that you would give it a type _or_ a protocol. They are different things - there is probably a better way to structure your code than that.

Comment: Note that this is approach is also very fragile. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/638fb92523dc6d0ba8392bc0a62f4030