# Swift: Determine whether a type conforms to protocol results an error

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

when I'm trying to determine whether a type conforms to a protocol I get an error:

> Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```swift
protocol FooProtocol {
    static func combine(foo: Self, with element: Any) -> Self
}

func combine<T>(foo: T, with element: Any) -> T? {
    if let F = T.self as? FooProtocol.Type { // Error in here
        return F.combine(foo: foo, with: element)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I know I can just do this:

```swift
func combine<T: FooProtocol>(foo: T, with element: Any) -> T {
    return T.combine(foo: foo, with: element)
}
```

But it's not what I need, what I need is that you can call the `combine(foo:with:)` function with any type, and if this type does not conform to `FooProtocol` then `nil` will get returned.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a runtime check for this. Just make two overloads.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a compile-time check with multiple overloads of this `combine` function, like so:

```
func combine<T: FooProtocol>(foo: T, with element: Any) -> T {
    T.combine(foo: foo, with: element)
}

func combine<T>(foo: T, with element: Any) -> T? {
    nil
}
```

Usage:

```
struct StructA: FooProtocol {
    /* conformance, etc... */
}

struct StructB {}

combine(foo: StructA(), with: 1) // Type of StructA
combine(foo: StructB(), with: "1") // Type of StructB?, return nil
```

This is the same concept as my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68713136/9607863).

Comment: This only works if the final type of foo can be proven to conform to FooProtocol at compile time. If the call to `combine` happens inside another generic method, or in a method that takes another protocol, this information will be lost, and the wrong method will be called. Ambiguous generic specializations are very fragile and the source of very frustrating bugs.

Comment: For some examples of how this fails, see https://gist.github.com/rnapier/6765a48a55d628433add84d0adadbf08

Comment: @RobNapier Thank you for adding that, that’s useful to know